# How do I "close" my index formula using IFS function?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get values extracted between a date range using the index formula and `IFS` function. However, I can only get one side of the range to work (the `>=` side).

In cell E5 I have used this formula:

```
=INDEX(IFS($A$5:$C$10>=$A$2,$A$5:$C$10,$A$5:$C$10<=$B$2,""))
```

[image]

If any of you have smarter ways to go about how to find specific dates in range, I'm open for suggestions.

```
=INDEX(IFS($A$5:$C$10>=$A$2,$A$5:$C$10,$A$5:$C$10<=$B$2,""))
```

Only getting dates smaller than a date in A2 removed and not greater than B2

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your expected output, please try

```
=Arrayformula(IF( (A5:C10>=A2)*(A5:C10<=B2), A5:C10,))
```

If you'd want one column with all matching dates, you could try

```
=query(transpose(split(textjoin(,1,query(A5:C10,,rows(A5:A10))), " ", 0)), "where Col1 >= date '"&text(A2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col1 <= date '"&text(B2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```